# File Upload urls have //chroot added to the url

Tags: file-uploads, image, focus-lab-master-config

I'm using the FocusLab Master Config set up which may be relevant. I haven't had any issues previously like this however.

I'm in the middle of migrating from Dev to a new live server and 90% of images on the site are not displaying due to incorrect urls being output.

For example:

```
<img src="//chrootuploads/slider/bagtoearth-reroof.jpg" width="1090" height="435" alt="" draggable="false">
```

should be

```
<img src="/uploads/slider/bagtoearth-reroof.jpg" width="1090" height="435" alt="" draggable="false">
```

When I check the file upload settings in the CP the path and url are correct, but on the front end the url is incorrect.

I can't figure out why /uploads is being replaced by //chrootuploads Of the five slides only one is being output correctly and resized with CE_image. Eveything else is doing this weird behavior and only on the live server (php 5.3.24).

Any ideas?

also interestingly random pages do not load - not even the 404 page, just a blank white screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image problem is usually caused by the setup at your hosting provider (Nexcess?).

I believe you can fix this by setting the correct base path for CE Image, [as described here](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/common-solutions).

EDIT:
And this is an example of how to set it at Nexcess:

```
$env_config['ce_image_document_root'] = '/chroot/home/account/domain/html';
```

Comment: So I would add this to config.prod.php correct?

Comment: Yes, or put it in config.master.php and use a conditional: if (ENV=='prod') { $env_config['ce_image_document_root'] = '/chroot/home/account/domain/html'; }